# How to configure pam-auth-update in non interactive mode?

Tags: shell, ldap, ubuntu-14.04, pam

I wanted to enable PAM module packages in non-interactive mode. Running `pam-auth-update` will prompt a wizard to enable the module packages. I wanted to enable the module package `[ ] Create home directory on login` without prompting the wizard screen. Please find the screenshot [image]

Is there any command to configure `pam-auth-update`.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/523880/pam-auth-update-without-the-text-ui

Answer (score 4):

The --enable switch was added to pam-auth-update in 1.1.8-3.7(debian) and is also available in Ubuntu since 18.04 it seems. 
So the current best solution would be `pam-auth-update --enable mkhomedir`

Comment: Works with 22.04

Comment: Also, to ensure no UI is ever shown, use `env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pam-auth-update --package`. I did with this and there was no prompt window.