# pam-auth-update non interactive mode not reflecting changes

Tags: linux, updates, pam, non-interactive

I want to run `pam-auth-update` on a specific profile in non-interactive mode. This must be run from a script so I cant work with an interface to enable.

I have already tried the following:

- `pam-auth-update --enable "my module"`
- `pam-auth-update --profile "my module"`
- `pam-auth-update --package "my module"`
- Tried using `--force` On all.
- Tried using `--tool config` on all, but that brings up the interactive interface again.

The first 3 commands ran, but when I run `pam-auth-update` my package is still not `*` selected. So I can tell if its enabled or not. How can I fix this?

I already saw this post, it was not helpful:
[How to configure pam-auth-update in non interactive mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389362/how-to-configure-pam-auth-update-in-non-interactive-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
The problem was I needed to use the file name of the pam module. I tried using the file full path, and the name, never tried the actual file name. So the file I was changing was `/usr/share/pam-configs/mkhomedir`

The correct way to invoke a non-interactive file is to do the following:

1. Make sure the file has `Session-Interactive-Only: yes` removed
2. Make sure to add `Default: yes` added to the module.
3. enable with `pam-auth-update --enable mkhomedir` with just the file name.